# Pass a variable with single quote groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

- I am trying to pass a parameter with singe quote in groovy

**example below**

> command "powershell write-host '$password' '$hostname'". I am trying to pass '$password' the whole name plus the single quote.
>
> What i have tried. \${password} \${hostname} . I used an escape variable however i am getting only $password but i want '$password'

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
echo " \"\${password}\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

"\'\${hostname}' \'\${password}'"

this worked for me